# SQLAlchemy operation logging

Tags: events, sqlalchemy, orm, audit-logging

I would like to log SQLAlchemy INSERT\UPDATE\DELETE operations after they have been committed into the database. Is there a way to this based on SQLAlchemy events?
Events, such as after_update, after_insert refer to Python objects, thus are not really helpful in case of a rollback, for example.